# Unable to install Backtrack 5

Tags: backtrack, startx

I'm using a Dell Inspiron 15r laptop with existing Windows 7 ultimate 32-bit operating system.

Now I want to install Backtrack 5 and dual boot. And I'm not able do it, getting the following errors:

I just log in with username `root` and password `toor`, then type `startx` to launch the GUI, but `startx` reports "command not found".

I've tried various commands such as `login` and `sh`, but no luck. `sudo` is out of the question, too.

Answer (score 0):

The `startx` script should be provided by the `xinit` package.
Check whether you have it installed:

```
dpkg --get-selections xinit
```

If it's not installed, then, as root, run `apt-get update; apt-get install xinit`.

If it's already installed, then run `apt-get update; apt-get install --reinstall xinit`